# Can a function feed two values into another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ran into a weird problem while trying to learn Python. I'm writing a piece of code that takes data from a .txt-file, feeds it into a function that modifies it heavily, and then feeds it to another function. It worked until I tried to split the data into two parts. I broke my code down and got this:

```
def func1(v1, v2):
    return(v1, v2)

def func2(v1, v2):
    return(v1, v2)

foo, bar = func1(func2("foo", "bar"))
```

func2 returns two values (in a tuple, I think?), but func1 needs two separated values - a tuple won't cut it. Is there a way to spit the tuple directly, or do I need to do the following?

```
foo, bar = func2("foo", "bar")
foo2, bar2 = func1(foo, bar)
```

There must be a better way... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unpack the tuple,

```
foo, bar = func1(*func2("foo", "bar"))
                 ^
```

Some more information [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: Wow, was it that easy? One asterisk had me pulling my hair out for half an hour. Thanks a lot for the quick reply.